# Find a polynomial such that f(T)=T* of a given linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose T is a normal operator on a finite-dimensional complex inner product space V with eigenvalues $\lambda_1=i,\lambda_2=1$ and $\lambda_3=0$. Find a polynomial f with degree $\le2$ such that $f(T)=T^*$.

I know that by Spectral Theorem, I can decompose T into $T^*=-iT_1+T_2$, but then I don't know what to do next.

Thank you

Comment: Don't you just want a quadratic polynomial $f$ such that $f(i),f(1),f(0)$ are the numbers $-i,1,0$?

Comment: Why?Would u explain a little bit more?

Comment: If $f$ is a polynomial, and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, isn't $f(\lambda)$ an eigenvalue of $f(T)$?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: So what you mean is that:
$T^*=-iT_1^*+T_2^*+0T_3^*$,  $T=iT_1+T_2+0T_3$, $f(T)=T^*$
Then using these three equalities and I can get the relation $f(i)=-i, f(1)=1, f(0)=0$

Comment: What I mean is you are looking for a polynomial $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, and I am suggesting that if you let $f(i)=-i$, $f(1)=1$, and $f(0)=0$, you get three (linear) equations for the three unknowns $a,b,c$.